# Redirecting to show User Profile rather than default home page when clicking to go "home"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

This question stems from the example web app created with Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, though it is not one of the exercises suggested by the author.

On many social sites, when clicking to go "home" (such as on the site logos), users are redirected to their profile rather than the default home page.  I was wondering how I may be able to accomplish this as well in the tutorial app.

In the tutorial app, the "home" view is considered "static", and rendered by a `static_page_controller` that just shows:

```
def home
end
```

When I tried to add the following to it:

```
def home
  if signed_in?
  redirect_to @user
  end
end
```

I get the error "cannot redirect to nil".  I had thought `@user` was shared across all the controllers (since `signed_in` was...  In the `user_controller`: `@user = User.find(params[:id])` ).  How would I modify the controller so that when it detects the user is signed in, the profile would be displayed rather than the home page?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `signed_in?` method do not use `current_user` instead of `@user`?

If so you can just change the line

```
redirect_to @user
```

to

```
redirect_to current_user
```